# Musical chairs with line texts in batch

Tags: batch-file

I still cannot find a solution to my problem.

**What I desire:** I have a txt file that contains 16 lines. Those lines begin with `.` and this is the only thing they have in common. To start with, all the content from line 16 is replaced by the content of line 15 and all line 15 is replaced by line 14 and so forth, until line 2 is replaced by line 1.

**Note:** the word LINE and numbers are just for reference. In fact, lines can have any alphanumeric character and also some special as `-`  `:`  `|` `*`. Lines can also be empty (only having the `.`)

[image]

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set y=c:\FILES\TEST.txt

set /a count=17

:A 
  set /a count-=1
```

*The first 'count' should be 16*

```
  for /f "delims=. tokens=%count%*" %%r in (%y%) do set L0=%%t
```

*tokens=16* or searches the whole txt for the 16th `.` character

```
  set L%count%=%L0:~1,133%
```

*variable L16 receives LINE16*

```
  echo !L%count%! -^> This must be line %count%
```

*LINE16 -> This must be line 16*

```
  if !count!==1 (goto B) else (goto A)
```

*As 16 is not 1, the next 'count' will GOTO A and receive 15*

```
:B
  set /a e=17
  set /a d=16
      
:N
  set /a e-=1
  set /a d-=1
```

*The first 'e' equals to 16 and 'd' equals to 15*

```
  call jrepl "!L%e%!" "!L%d%!" /F %y% /M /O -
```

*The first 'count' would replace "!L16!" to "!L15!"*

```
  echo !L%e%! -^> This must be line %e%
```

*LINE16 -> This must be line 16*

```
  if !e!==2 (goto EOF) else (goto N)
```

*As 16 is not 1, the next 'e' will GOTO N and receive 15*

```
:EOF
 echo END
 exit/b
```

---

**Another viewpoint that gives the same output is:**

[image]

Comment: in other words, you want to insert a new line a the first line (and delete the last line instead)?

Comment: @Gerhard. No, I want the new input (program that updates the txt file) to replace the first line and move all the other lines down. The 16th line, which is the last, will then be deleted in the process. There should be only 16 lines (including the update).

Comment: @Stephan Almost that. Indeed I want to insert a new line and this update will stay at the top (first line). However, before that, the first line has to be moved to occupy the place of the second line. So, the first line is now empty, just waiting for the update. It means that all the lines will be moved down, one by one. This process works if the last line is moved before all others, which means that the 16th line (last line) has to be deleted to make room from the 15th line.

Comment: So, are you wanting to delete the last line of the file? or insert a line _(containing nothing? or a period?)_, to the top of a file, as well as deleting the last line?

Comment: @Compo. Partially correct. Delete last line. Move all the others down of one line. Make room for the first line to receive an update. Imagine this as being the Star Wars opening crawl.

Comment: You now have three different answers from three different people, which all do what you're after (at least how the three of us independently understand you). Until now you either ignored them or just named them "not reproducible".  Until you don't describe *how*  they don't do what you want (how the result differs from the desired result), we are not able to help you further.

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question, which results in invalidating one or more Answers, is against policy. Your edits here did so. The policy is that any user with edit privileges should proactively revert such changes. I have reverted those edits. You *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](/questions/ask)*, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by saying that I'm astounded that you've got a program/process which writes to the first line of an existing file, overwriting the existing content/without a carriage return.

This solution is similar to Stephans existing answer, but all within one step:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "y=C:\FILES\TEST.txt"
Rem Create backup.
Copy /Y "%y%" "backup.tmp" 1> NUL 2>&1 || Exit /B
Rem Single step task.
(   Echo(
    For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%G In (
        '%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /BLN "." "backup.tmp"^
         ^| %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /BR "[123456789]: 1[012345]:"'
    ) Do Echo %%H
) 1> "%y%"
Rem Optionally delete backup.
Rem Del "backup.tmp"
```

The last line is `Rem`arked, it is a copy of your before file, do not unremark it for actual deletion until you're sure that the resultant `test.txt` content is what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, I can do it with this single line: `call jrepl "^^" "" /jendln "if (ln==1) $txt='%msg%'" /f "TEST.txt" /o -`, where `msg` is the machine information that will be placed on the first line. Please, see my update. I will be glad if we could make it work from this point on.

Comment: Good for you @kemilljeans, but I have absolutely no interest in using a huge third party JScript/Batch all in one utility, especially one which did not form part of the question tags or provided code. If you want to select your own solution post it as one, or accept one of the provided answers, which does answer your question using the parameters you initially laid out